# Procedure to import excel file to access is erroring out after loop - MS Access Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm getting an error message after the last loop runs in this procedure.The error is received after it cycles through the last worksheet in the excel workbook, and the line is "xl.ActiveSheet.Next.Select" (line 17 from the bottom). Can anyone give me a pointer? I've read and been told using .select is not ideal, but this is an older database I have inherited and would like to resolve this issue before improving the code.

The loop opens up an excel file and cycles through each worksheet (24 in this workbook) and imports the data to an access database. I've searched this topic but many issues seem unrelated, or much simpler to debug. I've even removed all but two worksheets and the error is still repeatable. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
Private Sub lbl_WV_import_Click()
If gcfHandleErrors Then On Error GoTo Err_frmMe_home_lbl_WV_import

Dim xl As Object, wrkbk1 As Object
Dim pcd As String, pcd_title As String, model As String, station As String, task As String, pic As String, bom_pn As String, c1 As String, c2 As String, spec As String, sApp As String
Dim pn As String, pname As String, ts_part_name As String, ts_part_num As String, model_info As String, color As String, dest As String, tool As String, socket As String, torque As String, misc As String
Dim rev As Integer, zone As Integer, seq As Integer, mod_id As Integer, delta As Integer, st_seq As Integer, qty As Integer, i As Integer, J As Integer, ts_sec As Integer, sec As Integer, row As Integer
Dim pcd_id As LongPtr, stat_id As LongPtr, task_id As LongPtr, task_list_id As LongPtr, pn_id As LongPtr, tool_id As LongPtr, task_step_id As LongPtr
Dim pitch As Double

Set db = CurrentDb()

sApp = "Excel.Application"
If IsAppRunning(sApp) = True Then
    Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    For Each wrkbk1 In xl.Workbooks
        If wrkbk1.Name = "P1_PCD.xlsm" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    strSQL = DLookup("db_loc", "tbl_ext_source") & DLookup("area", "tblArea") & "\P1_PCD.xlsm"
    Set wrkbk1 = xl.Workbooks.Open(strSQL)
Else
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Application.Visible = True
    strSQL = DLookup("db_loc", "tbl_ext_source") & DLookup("area", "tblArea") & "\P1_PCD.xlsm"
    Set wrkbk1 = xl.Workbooks.Open(strSQL)
End If
            
xl.Workbooks("P1_PCD.xlsm").Activate
xl.Sheets(1).Select
xl.Range("B1").Select
pcd_title = xl.Range("B1").Value
xl.Range("O2").Select
pitch = xl.Range("O2").Value
xl.Range("Q2").Select
pcd = "PCD-" & xl.Range("Q2").Value
xl.Range("R2").Select
rev = xl.Range("R2").Value
xl.Range("K3").Select
model = xl.Range("K3").Value
If IsNull(DLookup("model", "tblModel", "[model] = '" & model & "'")) Then
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblModel (model) " _
    & "Values ('" & model & "')"
    db.Execute strSQL
            
    lid = DMax("mod_id", "tblModel")

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
    & "tblAudit (EditDate, RecordSource, RecordID, User, Field, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
    & "VALUES (Now(), ""tblModel"", '" & lid & "', '" & fosUserName() & "', ""model"", ""New Record"", '" & model & "')"
    db.Execute strSQL
End If
        
If IsNull(DLookup("pcd", "tblPCD", "pcd='" & pcd & "' AND rev=" & rev & "")) Then
    mod_id = DLookup("mod_id", "tblModel", "[model] = '" & model & "'")
    bom_pn = DLookup("ItemNo", "PYMAC", "LV = ""00""")
    
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblPCD ( pcd, pcd_title, rev, mod_id, pitch, pre_rev, bom_pn ) " _
    & "VALUES ('" & pcd & "','" & pcd_title & "', " & rev & ", " & mod_id & ", " & pitch & ", " & rev - 1 & ", '" & bom_pn & "')"
    db.Execute strSQL
    pcd_id = DLookup("pcd_id", "tblPCD", "pcd='" & pcd & "' AND rev=" & rev & "")
            
    lid = DMax("pcd_id", "tblPCD")
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
    & "tblAudit (EditDate, RecordSource, RecordID, User, Field, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
    & "VALUES (Now(), ""tblPCD"", '" & lid & "', '" & fosUserName() & "', ""ALL"", ""New Record"", ""New PCD from excel "" & " & pcd_id & ")"
    db.Execute strSQL

    Call upload_pymac(pcd_id)
    Set db = CurrentDb()
Else
    If InputBox("This PCD already exists. Is this another section of this PCD that needs to be imported? [Y/N]") = "y" Then
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
pcd_id = DLookup("pcd_id", "tblPCD", "pcd='" & pcd & "' AND rev=" & rev & "")
    If IsNull(DMax("seq", "tblTask", "[pcd_id] = " & pcd_id & "")) Then
        seq = 1
    Else
        seq = DMax("seq", "tblTask", "[pcd_id] = " & pcd_id & "")
    End If
    
For J = 1 To xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    xl.Range("O3").Select
    station = xl.Range("O3").Value
    If IsNull(DLookup("station", "tblStation", "[station] = '" & station & "'")) Then
        If IsNull(DMax("stat_id", "tblStation")) Then
            sec = 1
        Else
            sec = DMax("stat_id", "tblStation") + 1
        End If
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblStation ( station, zone_id,sec ) " _
        & "VALUES ('" & station & "',1," & sec & ")"
        db.Execute strSQL
            
        lid = DMax("stat_id", "tblStation")
                
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
        & "tblAudit (EditDate, RecordSource, RecordID, User, Field, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
        & "VALUES (Now(), ""tblStation"", '" & lid & "', '" & fosUserName() & "', ""ALL"", ""New Records"", ""New record for PCD "" & " & pcd_id & ")"
        db.Execute strSQL
            
    End If
    stat_id = DLookup("stat_id", "tblStation", "[station] = '" & station & "'")
        
    st_seq = 1
    c1 = "C6"
    xl.Range(c1).Select
        
    Do Until xl.CountA(xl.ActiveCell) = 0
        xl.Range(c1).Select
        task = xl.ActiveCell.Value
        
        If Len(task) > 250 Then
            task = Left(task, 255)
        End If
        
        If IsNull(DLookup("task_txt", "tblTask_txt", "[task_txt] = '" & task & "'")) Then
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTask_txt ( task_txt ) " _
            & "VALUES ('" & task & "')"
            db.Execute strSQL
            
            lid = DMax("task_list_id", "tblTask_txt")

            strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
            & "tblAudit (EditDate, RecordSource, RecordID, User, Field, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
            & "VALUES (Now(), ""tblTask_txt"", '" & lid & "', '" & fosUserName() & "', ""task_txt"", ""New Record"", '" & task & "')"
            db.Execute strSQL
        End If
        task_list_id = DLookup("task_list_id", "tblTask_txt", "[task_txt] = '" & task & "'")
          
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
        
        If xl.ActiveCell.Value = "Q" Then
            delta = 1
        ElseIf xl.ActiveCell.Value = "C" Then
            delta = 2
        ElseIf xl.ActiveCell.Value = "CTQ" Then
            delta = 3
        ElseIf xl.ActiveCell.Value = "R" Then
            delta = 4
        Else
            delta = 0
        End If
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        spec = Replace(xl.ActiveCell.Value, "'", "''")
        If Len(spec) > 250 Then
            spec = Left(spec, 255)
        End If
        
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTask ( pcd_id, seq, stat_id, task_list_id, st_seq, spec_inst ) " _
        & "Values (" & pcd_id & ", " & seq & ", " & stat_id & ", " & task_list_id & "," & st_seq & ", '" & spec & "')"
        db.Execute strSQL
        task_id = DMax("task_id", "tblTask")
        
        lid = DMax("task_id", "tblTask")

        strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
        & "tblAudit (EditDate, RecordSource, RecordID, User, Field, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
        & "VALUES (Now(), ""tblTask_txt"", '" & lid & "', '" & fosUserName() & "', ""ALL"", ""New Record"", ""New record for PCD "" & " & pcd_id & ")"
        db.Execute strSQL
        
        row = xl.ActiveCell.row()
        c2 = "E" & row
            xl.Range(c2).Select
        strSQL = DLookup("db_loc", "tbl_ext_source") & DLookup("area", "tblArea") & "\PICS\" & task_id & ".jpg"
        xl.Run "getpic", strSQL

        For i = 1 To 10
        c2 = "K" & row & ":" & "T" & row
        
        If xl.CountA(xl.Range(c2)) = 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
        
        c2 = "K" & row
        xl.Range(c2).Select
        c2 = xl.ActiveCell.Address
        ts_part_num = ""
        ts_part_name = ""
        pn = ""
        pname = ""
        pn_id = 0
        tool = ""
        tool_id = 0
        
        pname = xl.ActiveCell.Value
        If pname = "Part Name" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        pn = xl.ActiveCell.Value
        If IsNull(DLookup("part_num", "tblPart_master", "[part_num] = '" & pn & "'")) Then
            ts_part_num = pn
            ts_part_name = pname
        Else
            pn_id = DLookup("pn_id", "tblPart_master", "[part_num] = '" & pn & "'")
        End If
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        qty = xl.ActiveCell.Value
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        model_info = xl.ActiveCell.Value
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        color = xl.ActiveCell.Value
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        dest = xl.ActiveCell.Value
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        tool = xl.ActiveCell.Value

        If Len(tool) > 1 Then
            If IsNull(DLookup("tool_id", "tblTools", "[tool] = '" & tool & "'")) Then
                strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTools (tool, tool_type_id ) " _
                & "Values ('" & tool & "',1)"
                db.Execute strSQL
                
                lid = DMax("tool_id", "tblTools")

                strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
                & "tblAudit (EditDate, RecordSource, RecordID, User, Field, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
                & "VALUES (Now(), ""tblTools"", '" & lid & "', '" & fosUserName() & "', ""tool"", ""New Record"", '" & tool & "')"
                db.Execute strSQL
            End If
            tool_id = DLookup("tool_id", "tblTools", "[tool] = '" & tool & "'")
        End If
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        socket = xl.ActiveCell.Value
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        torque = xl.ActiveCell.Value
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        misc = xl.ActiveCell.Value
        
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTask_steps ( task_id ) " _
            & " Values ( " & task_id & " )"
            db.Execute strSQL
            task_step_id = DMax("task_step_id", "tblTask_steps")

            strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
            & "tblAudit (EditDate, RecordSource, RecordID, User, Field, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
            & "VALUES (Now(), ""tblTask_steps"", '" & task_step_id & "', '" & fosUserName() & "', ""ALL"", ""New Record"", ""New record for PCD "" & " & pcd_id & ")"
            db.Execute strSQL
            
            strSQL = "SELECT tblTask_steps.* " _
            & "FROM tblTask_steps " _
            & "WHERE (((tblTask_steps.task_step_id)=" & task_step_id & "))"
            Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
            
            If Len(ts_part_name) > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!ts_part_name = ts_part_name
                rs.Update
            End If
            If Len(ts_part_num) > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!ts_part_num = ts_part_num
                rs.Update
            End If
            If pn_id > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!pn_id = pn_id
                rs.Update
            End If
            If qty > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!qty = qty
                rs.Update
            End If
            If Len(model_info) > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!model_info = model_info
                rs.Update
            End If
            If Len(color) > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!color = color
                rs.Update
            End If
            If Len(dest) > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!dest = dest
                rs.Update
            End If
            If tool_id > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!tool_id = tool_id
                rs.Update
            End If
            If Len(socket) > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!socket = socket
                rs.Update
            End If
            If Len(torque) > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!torque = torque
                rs.Update
            End If
            If delta > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!delta = delta
                rs.Update
            End If
            If Len(misc) > 0 Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!misc = misc
                rs.Update
            End If
            
        xl.Range(c2).Select
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        row = xl.ActiveCell.row()
        
        Next i
        ts_sec = 0
        xl.Range(c1).Select
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If xl.ActiveCell.Column() <> 3 Then
            row = xl.ActiveCell.row()
            c1 = "C" & row + 1
            xl.Range(c1).Select
        End If
        If xl.ActiveCell.Value = "Task Description" Then
            xl.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            If xl.ActiveCell.Column() <> 3 Then
                row = xl.ActiveCell.row()
                c1 = "C" & row + 1
                xl.Range(c1).Select
            End If
        End If
        If IsEmpty(xl.ActiveCell) Then
            strSQL = DLookup("db_loc", "tbl_ext_source") & DLookup("area", "tblArea") & "\PICS\" & task_id & "_2.jpg"
            xl.Run "getpic", strSQL
            xl.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            If xl.ActiveCell.Column() <> 3 Then
                row = xl.ActiveCell.row()
                c1 = "C" & row + 1
                xl.Range(c1).Select
            End If
        End If
        If xl.ActiveCell.Value = "Task Description" Then
            xl.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            If xl.ActiveCell.Column() <> 3 Then
                row = xl.ActiveCell.row()
                c1 = "C" & row + 1
                xl.Range(c1).Select
            End If
        End If
        c1 = xl.ActiveCell.Address
        st_seq = st_seq + 1
        seq = seq + 1
        Loop
        xl.ActiveSheet.Next.Select
        Next J
        
        xl.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       
strSQL = "UPDATE tblTask SET tblTask.image_id = [task_id] " _
& "WHERE (((tblTask.pcd_id)=" & pcd_id & "))"
db.Execute strSQL

Call recal_secs(1, pcd_id, 0)
Call sort_stat_all(pcd_id)

MsgBox "The PCD has been imported. Go to stations and assure the zones are correct."
        
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

Exit_frmMe_home_lbl_WV_import:
Exit Sub
Err_frmMe_home_lbl_WV_import:
Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "frmMe_home_lbl_WV_import()")
Resume Exit_frmMe_home_lbl_WV_import

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is primitive in terms of Excel handling, no offence... Selecting in your code context only consumes Excel resources without bringing any benefit. I suppose that the problematic line has reached the last sheet and `ActiveSheet.Next` does not exist. When your code stops on the respective error, moving cursor over `j` variable, what does it display? Isn't it the last sheet of the processed workbook? If you like the code as it is, you may escape the error placing before the problematic code line:  `If J = xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count Then Exit For`

Comment: But your code can be adapted to work 100 times faster than in the way you use Excel Object...

Comment: Thank you @FaneDuru. That worked like a charm. And no offence taken. I know this needs to be updated and is quite antiquated. I'll look for some resources to sharpen this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tried suggesting in my above comment, it looks that the way you designed the code (probably, mostly based on macro recorder...), using an unjustified number of selecting, makes the code erroring on the respective line because of the fact that a `Next` sheet does not exist after the last one...

If you want keeping the code as it is and only solve the error, please, try inserting above the problematic code line, the next one:

```
   If J = xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count Then Exit For
```

But your code is not efficient, at all. The next part, for instance:

```
xl.Workbooks("P1_PCD.xlsm").Activate
xl.Sheets(1).Select
xl.Range("B1").Select
pcd_title = xl.Range("B1").value
```

should be replaced with the more efficient one, not involving any Activation/selection:

```
Dim ws As Object
  Set ws = xl.Workbooks("P1_PCD.xlsm")
  pcd_title = ws.Range("B1").value
```

Then, the way of looping between the sheets is also not efficient. Activating the sheet and selecting any range to be used only consumes Excel resources. Instead of the way you use:

```
  For J = 1 To xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
```

you can do it in a different, more efficient way:

```
 Dim sh As Object
 For each sh in xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    station = sh.Range("O3").Value
    'your code...
    'instead of
     'xl.Range(c1).Select
     'task = xl.ActiveCell.Value
    'you should use:
    task = sh.Range(c1).Value ' or better
    task = sh.Range("C6").Value 'and eliminate c1 useless variable...

    'it is at least strange to use
    'c1 = "C" & row + 1
    'xl.Range(c1).Select
    'instead of directly:
    sh.Range("C" & row + 1) 'selection is useless, anyhow...

 Next sh
```

Your code is too long, you do not explain in words what you want accomplishing and I cannot spend too much time to deduce what you try doing. I am only suggesting some things necessary to be changed in order to improve the code quality and speed...